# Get "leading comments" from CSV with Apache Commons CSV

Tags: java, csv

The Apache Commons CSV library can deal with comments by attaching the comment to the following record. Is there a way to access comments that come before the header line?
In the code below is there a way to access the text "leading" "comments" which comes at the start of the file?
I can do this by not specifying `setHeaders` in the format but then I don't get the header processing.
I know I can't get the "trailing comment", I understand why and I'm ok with that.

```
package com.nowhere;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (Reader reader = new StringReader(DATA); CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(reader, FORMAT)) {
            for (CSVRecord rec : parser) {
                System.out.println(rec);
            }
        }
    }

    public static final CSVFormat FORMAT = CSVFormat.Builder.create(CSVFormat.EXCEL).setCommentMarker(';').setHeader().build();
    public static final String DATA = """
            ; leading
            ; comments
            "a","b","c"
            1,2,3
            ; trailing comment
            """;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Apache Commons CSV 1.10, you can do this with [getHeaderComment()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html#getHeaderComment--)